# Move Workflow from one library to another the version history is not synced and the file is not overwritten how do we do this?

Tags: workflow-history

I have created a workflow that uses the move file from a draft library to a Live and Archive Library, the move works fine and the file is moved. However the issue I am experiencing is this.

In Draft the file is a version 0.4 and when I move this to live I want this to be made a major version which again works fine the first time, as the Live library has Major versioning set, the problem happens when I change draft to 0.5 and use the Move to Live Workflow, it just adds another file with a slightly different naming convention and still makes it a 1.0, what I want to happen is for it to update the current version by overwriting the file with the same name and making this a version 2.0

How do I do this?